# build fails when opening view controller based on identifier from within URLRequest dataTask

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a class BaseViewController that has the following function (AKSwiftSlideMenu):

```
func openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier(_ strIdentifier:String){
    let destViewController : UIViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: strIdentifier)

    let topViewController : UIViewController = self.navigationController!.topViewController!

    if (topViewController.restorationIdentifier! == destViewController.restorationIdentifier!){
        print("Same VC")
    } else {
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(destViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

There is a view controller class based  on BaseViewController that does a login check and includes some controllers including 2 text field controllers and a button. following code is attached to button's IBAction:

```
@IBAction func btn_login_pressed(_ sender: Any) { 
    //self.openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier("logged")
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://someURL/login?Username="+(text_email.text)!+"&Password="+(text_password.text)!)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = ""
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        let dict = self.convertToDictionary(text: responseString!)
        let status:Int = dict?["Status"] as! Int

        if(status==0){
        print("fail")
        } else {
        self.openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier("logged")
        }  
    }
    task.resume()
    //self.openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier("logged")
 }
```

if i use self.openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier before task or after task.resume() then all is fine and the app opens the new view controller. On the other hand, when i try to use the function after receiving the online data i do nor get a build error. Code runs, accesses online data. Dict gets its values. Then there is a lot of waiting involved and i get the following message in output:

2017-05-07 16:27:25.301 myApp[9788:3330252] This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.

sometimes new view is loaded and sometimes it fails.

on the other hand, stuff written after task.resume() line seems to happen before i get the online login data.

So my question is how do i access self.openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier function after getting the online data.

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that all UI work is done on the main thread. try wrapping your code in a dispatch block to use the main thread

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // init your views here
    let destViewController : UIViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: strIdentifier)

    let topViewController : UIViewController =     self.navigationController!.topViewController!

    if (topViewController.restorationIdentifier! == destViewController.restorationIdentifier!){
        print("Same VC")
    } else {
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(destViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

When you make a network request, it runs asynchronously on a background thread. So when you get a response and want to then do something with your user interface, you need to ensure this is done on the main thread.

Because the network request is async and runs on the background thread. you will notice that code before and after the task.resume normally runs before you get the response for example:

```
print("before async")

// shortened async task
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    print("response received")
}
task.resume()

print("after async")
```

the expected output here would be:

> before async
>
> after async
>
> response received

Comment: what do you get in your console? if the response fails, then the guard statements would exit early and prevent your view showing also

Comment: thanks. this works. unfortunately i am unable to up vote  due to low score )-: